# How to see the parameters that were passed into a contract call?

Tags: polkadot-js, smart-contract

I want to know the contract address, contract caller, and what parameters were passed into the contract call but in the Polkadot.js UI, the presented fields don't seem to be helpful.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caller is the signer of the extrinsic, contract address is the first argument (which named `dest`), parameters is the last argument (named `data`) but without contract definition it cannot be decoded.

Comment: So if I have the contract definition, how can I decode it?

Comment: @MinhMốc seems the parameters are encoded as the same codec as substrate txs, you may use `@polkadot/types` to decode it with the type metadata from ABI.